# type signature golfing (or not) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Could GHC golf out this extra type annotation or does it bring something real ?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module SOQuestionInstanceQuantification2 where

class IsomorphismFromTo a b where --  :~:
  isofromto :: forall p. p a -> p b
  to :: a -> b
  --to = (isofromto) @((->) a) id -- Bad without (redundant ?) annotation
  to = (isofromto :: (forall p. p a -> p b)) @((->) a) id -- Good with (redundant ?) annotation
```

edit : removed superfluous `DefaultSignatures`

Comment: Um... you don't need any of that `DefaultSignatures` or `TypeApplications` tooling here, plain old `to = isofromto id` does the trick...

Comment: for this particular example, yes. but in general, assigning a type signature changes the meaning of a term (which is useful to debug and pin things down) so I wonder if I missed something or if it's just a GHC/extension quirk. That said, I can reduce my example with your suggestion, it stays without `DefaultSignatures`

Comment: ps : as we are likely to pin things down when we investigate some issue, it's annoying to introduce a new "type bug" while doing so. so it's a bit more serious than just golfing...

Comment: I showed you how to do this in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423390/791604)...

Comment: @DanielWagner indeed, I did not realize that the `a` and `b` were free in the context of a class declaration. I am still processing your previous answer, which is quite nice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *real* signature of `isofromto` includes the type variables from the class:

```
isofromto :: forall a b. IsomorphismFromTo a b => forall p. p a -> p b
```

Therefore, if we want to be explicit on `p`, we need to write

```
to = isofromto @a @b @((->) a) id
```

to pass those argument as well. Alternatively,

```
to = isofromto @_ @_ @((->) a) id
```

makes those arguments to be inferred.

In the longer alternative

```
to = (isofromto :: (forall p. p a -> p b)) @((->) a) id
```

the signature is not redundant, since it fixes the `a` and `b` type arguments.

Note that, in the general case, having to pass these additional arguments is needed since we might want to call, within `to @a @b`, an implementation of `isofromto` from another instance e.g. `isofromto @(a,b) @(b,a)`.

Of course, Haskell could have a notation to indicate "call `isofromto` from the current instance", without additional type arguments, but has not. I guess in regular programming type inference already covers most cases, and when it's not enough, type applications already provide a means to choose the instance we need (including the current one), so I guess there is no strong need for such a special notation.

Comment: of course !! In `(isofromto :: (forall p. p a -> p b)) @((->) a)`  the type applies to `p`, which should be a functor. In `(isofromto) @((->) a)` GHC tries to fill the **first** type hole of `isofromto`, which is `a :: *` that's why it rightly complains "Expecting one more argument to ‘(->) a’
  Expected a type, but ‘(->) a’ has kind ‘* -> *’"

Comment: Adding more ad hoc stuff to the already ad hoc defaulting mechanism doesn't seem like a great idea to me. Best to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of question in the future, you can ask ghci what's going on:

```
> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls
> :t +v isofromto
isofromto
  :: forall a b (p :: * -> *). IsomorphismFromTo a b => p a -> p b
```

This makes it very clear that `a` and `b` are the first two type arguments. I recommend adding something like this to your `~/.ghci`; it's quietly saved my bacon a bunch of times.

```
:set -fprint-explicit-foralls
:def t Prelude.return Prelude.. (":type +v "Prelude.++)
```

The second line aliases `:t` to `:type +v`, so you don't need to remember the `+v` when you need it most. In the rare case that you actually want `:t` without `+v`, it is still available as `:type`.

These two pieces together (`+v` and `print-explicit-foralls`) will show you which type variables (if any) are available for application, and in which order. Type variables that are not available for type application will be enclosed in curly braces:

```
> :t +v id id
id id :: forall {a}. a -> a
```

Missing one or the other of `print-explicit-foralls` or `+v` will lie in some situations.

Comment: nb : (in case someone else reads that) you need a ":def!", at least in my version otherwise `macro 't' overwrites builtin command.  Use ':def!' to overwrite.`  great tip !