# Types we can prove things about in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

Can we prove isomorphism involving native types in Haskell ?

```
import Prelude

newtype Leibniz a b = Leibniz {unLeibniz :: forall f. f a -> f b}


data One = One

-- `u` and `v` are inverse
u :: Bool -> Either One One
u b = if b then Right One else Left One

v :: Either One One -> Bool
v = \case
  (Left _) -> False
  (Right _) -> True

--- Can we prove proof that ?
p :: Leibniz Bool (Either One One)
p = Leibniz (\(x :: f Bool) -> __ :: f (Either One One))
```

Comment: Library recommendation requests are off-topic on SO, because answers to that kind of question are unusually likely to go out of date. I'm going to remove that part of your question shortly, if only to protect you from the question getting closed.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems to me that the `Leibniz` type is uninhabited, except in the case that `a` and `b` are the same type (not isomorphic, but actually the same). Am I wrong? Or is that type still useful somehow?

Comment: @amalloy You are not missing anything; `Leibniz` is inhabited exactly when `a` and `b` are the same type. As in my answer, `:~:` gives us a canonical counterexample for all other pairs of types. However, it could still be useful, maybe, for similar reasons to `:~:` being useful.

Comment: @amalloy my question was a bit awkward. to add up to Daniel, Leibniz with no constraint, as written here, is the strongest form of equality. Which is good in the sense that is you have a term of this type, you can apply it anywhere. For instance, you can't derive any `Coercible` instance, they are computed by the compiler. Yet with a `Leibniz a b` witness, you can derive a `Coercible a b`, so even compiler respects it. In general this is used in compiler as they generate such equality if "represented" type (aka a value, than happens to describe a type for your language) match

Comment: ```data Dict c = c => Dict

newtype DC a b = DC {unDC :: Dict (Coercible a a) -> Dict (Coercible a b)}

leibnizToCoercible :: forall a b. Leibniz a b -> Dict (Coercible a b)
leibnizToCoercible (Leibniz ab) = (unDC . ab . DC) id Dict```

Comment: if you are building your type system on top of haskell, you would add an expression language on top of Leibniz.  This is a great read if you didn't already https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Typing-dynamic-typing-Baars-Swierstra/09ee3459fea8385bf759f64c65fc81cbe032146a

Comment: In https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Typing-dynamic-typing-Baars-Swierstra/09ee3459fea8385bf759f64c65fc81cbe032146a they add only list and functions, but you could add +, * etc.. Those constructors, when seen (very?) abstractly, are just providing iso so that adjunct "change of base" lift to adjunct morphism of endofunctors (and types are fixpoint of those)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there is no good term of type `Leibniz Bool (Either One One)`. Indeed, there are "strange" `f`s where we can't do that conversion; the trivial example is that [`Bool :~: Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#t::-126-:) is inhabited but `Bool :~: Either One One` isn't, and so if `f = (:~:) Bool` then there is no function of type `f Bool -> f (Either One One)`.

BUT if you modify `Leibniz` slightly:

```
newtype Leibniz a b = Leibniz {unLeibniz :: forall f. IsoFunctor f => f a -> f b}
```

Here, `IsoFunctor` is a new class like `Functor` except it demands pure mappings in both directions:

```
class IsoFunctor f where isomap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> f a -> f b
```

This class rules out types whose argument is nominal, rather than representational, like `(:~:) Bool`. (And, in the other direction, an instance can always be written for types that have the right kind and are representational in their argument.) Then we can write:

```
p :: Leibniz Bool (Either One One)
p = Leibniz (isomap u v)
```

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't (and in general, can't) guarantee that `u` and `v` are inverse.

Comment: of course. why do I keep forgetting about this... I think I have code that restrict the iso to the correct role (somewhere). I'll add it as a comment if I find it.

Comment: you who gave it ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422162/avoid-unsafecoerce-with-some-coercible-use-case

Comment: The mapping looks like a functor from the "maximal groupoid" of Hask (which embeds into Twisted Hask) whose hom-set is being defined